# Route inside route not work for me in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a website that I'm building and an admin dashboard that I want to go to. I have a page that has an `<Outlet/>` inside it, and only when I go to the `admin-dashboard` address it works, but if I add a path, it leaves me from the page where I have the `<Outlet/>`.

This is my page with `<Outlet/>` code:

```
const Layout = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const dreWidth = window.screen.width > 1000 ? open ? 300 : 100 : null 
  return (
    <Box>
      {props.adminPath && <MiniDrawer open={open} setOpen={setOpen} logged={props.logCheck} auth={props.auth}/>}
      <Box
        component='main'
        style={{ flexGrow: 1, padding: 3, width: `calc(100% - ${dreWidth}px)` , transition : '0.5s' , float: 'left' }}
      >
        <Toolbar style={{ minHeight: "1.875rem" }} />
        <Box style={{ margin: "1rem 2rem" }}>
          <Outlet />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

This is main with the Routers :

```
const MainPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth.auth);
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users.users);
  const { pathname } = useLocation()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(LoadUser())
    dispatch(getAllUsers())
  }, [dispatch])

  let logCheck = token
  let user = users.find(user => user.id === auth.id)

  let adminPath = pathname === '/admin-dashboard'

  return (
    <>
      <Box>
      {!adminPath && <Header logged={logCheck} user={user} auth={auth}/>}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/join-to-course" element={logCheck ? <Navigate to='/'/> :<JoinToCourse />} />
          <Route path="/join" element={logCheck ? <Navigate to='/'/> : <MainJoinToCourse />} />
          <Route path="/join/:orderId" element={logCheck ? <Navigate to='/'/> : <PaymentPage />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={logCheck ? <Navigate to='/'/> : <LoginPage />} />
          <Route path="admin-dashboard" element={logCheck ? <Layout adminPath={adminPath} user={user} auth={auth}/> : <Navigate to='/' />}>
            <Route path="" element={<Dashboard />}/>
            <Route path="home-page" element={<HomePageContents />}/>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <BackToTop />
      </Box>
      {!adminPath && <Footer />}
    </>
  );
};

export default MainPage;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "but if I add a path, it leaves me from the page where I have the `<Outlet/>`"? It's not clear what any issue is.

Comment: if im in the path for example 'localhost:3000/admin-dashboard' its ok and work is in the same page but if I add the path 'localhost:3000/admin-dashboard/home-page' its go to different site .

Comment: Wouldn't that be the expected behavior? `"/admin-dashboard/home-page"` is a different path and the `HomePageContents` component would be rendered. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Are you just trying to conditionally render the `Header` component based on route?

Comment: i solve the problem ,
i write in new comment 
thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter I just changed the code
from this :

```
let adminPath = pathname === '/admin-dashboard'
```

to this :

```
let adminPath = pathname.includes('/admin-dashboard')
```

now its work

Comment: You should note that a substring match such as this will also return true for a completely different path which just includes this substring.
ex: `/admin-dashboard-but-not-really`

Also, upon a quick look at the docs, react router provides [a hook](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match) and [a matchPath function](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/match-path) that may prove useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question/issue you appear to want to conditionally render the `Header` component on non-admin routes.

Create another layout that renders `Header` and an `Outlet`, similar to the existing `Layout` component.

Non-Admin layout

```
const Layout = () => {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth.auth);
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users.users);

  const user = users.find(user => user.id === auth.id);

  return (
    <>
      <Header logged={token} user={user} auth={auth}/>
      <Box style={{ margin: "1rem 2rem" }}>
        <Outlet />
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <BackToTop />
      </Box>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

Admin layout

```
const AdminLayout = () => {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth.auth);
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users.users);

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const dreWidth = window.screen.width > 1000 ? open ? 300 : 100 : null 
  return (
    <Box>
      <MiniDrawer open={open} setOpen={setOpen} logged={token} auth={auth} />
      <Box
        component='main'
        style={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          padding: 3,
          width: `calc(100% - ${dreWidth}px)`,
          transition : '0.5s',
          float: 'left'
        }}
      >
        <Toolbar style={{ minHeight: "1.875rem" }} />
        <Box style={{ margin: "1rem 2rem" }}>
          <Outlet />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

It seems you are also using a token value stored in state to conditionally render a routed component or the `Navigate` component. For simplicity of routing I'd suggest also creating protected layout routes as well.

ProtectedRoute

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);

  if (token === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  return token ? <Outlet> : <Navigate to='/' replace />;
};
```

AnonymousRoute

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AnonymousRoute = () => {
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);

  if (token === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  return token ? <Navigate to='/' replace /> : <Outlet>;
};
```

Main

```
const MainPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(LoadUser());
    dispatch(getAllUsers());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Box>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route element={<AnonymousRoute />}>
            <Route path="/join-to-course" element={<JoinToCourse />} />
            <Route path="/join" element={<MainJoinToCourse />} />
            <Route path="/join/:orderId" element={<PaymentPage />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path="admin-dashboard" element={<AdminLayout />}>
            <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="home-page" element={<HomePageContents />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Box>
  );
};
```